# SQL Server create date

Tags: sql-server

Can we create a date using SQL Server 2005 ?

Example if I have year = 2010, month = 11, and day = 2, how can I convert or create it to datetime?

Below is if we write it in javascript

```
var date = new Date(2010, 10, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

and this is with oracle

```
SELECT TO_DATE('2010-11-02', 'YYYY-MM-DD') FROM DUAL
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're working with strings, and wanting to convert to a datetime data type, it's best to work with strings that can be unambiguously converted to datetimes. The following formats can all be converted to datetime values by SQL (either via CONVERT, or letting SQL Server do the conversion implicitly) without any ambiguity:

```
'20101102'

'2010-11-02T10:59:59'

'2010-11-02T10:59:59.997'
```

In all of the above formats, the date components are arranged as 4 digit year, then month, then day. Other formats that look trivially similar (e.g. `'2010-11-02'`) may be converted to different values, depending on the language settings for your connection (but Dogget's answer is still valid, because he's using it in an ODBC literal expression, which is well defined - surrounding it with the `{d }` characters)

Comment: Sorry, you're wrong: `xxxx-xx-xx` by default is always threated as `yyyy-MM-dd`, not as `yyyy-dd-MM`: `select cast ('2010-11-02' as datetime)`

Comment: @abatishchev - `set language 'british english' select cast ('2010-11-02' as datetime)` - result: 2010-02-11 00:00:00.000

Comment: @abatishchev - and to prove it's getting it wrong on input, not output - `set language 'british english' select DATEPART(month,cast ('2010-11-02' as datetime))` returns 2

Comment: Probably, by default, without explicit indication, `yyyy-MM-dd` is default date format. I think so because both american english SQL Server 2008 (en-US everywhere) and russian SQL Server 2008 (ru-RU everywhere) works in the same manner (as I described). Why can it be?

Comment: @abatishchev - I'm not sure what you're asking now. But it's why I was careful to point out that the dashed format is ambiguous - because I know from painful experience that it is. Besides, once you know that YYYYMMDD (without dashes) isn't ambiguous, you actually save yourself two characters every time :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can do `SELECT {d '2010-11-02'}` have to use this exact format though

Answer (score 1):

Specify the **style** in the argument to the convert function.
See the msdn help on [convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) for the different values.

```
select convert(datetime, '2010-11-02', 120)
...
2010-11-02 00:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 0):

`select convert(datetime, convert(char(8), 20101102))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `select convert(datetime, '11-11-2010')` to convert to datetime.

Comment: That format is ambiguous - depending on language settings, SQL Server might interpret that string as MM-DD-YYYY or DD-MM-YYYY.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `set @datevar='20101102';`.
This is language-neutral and will be converted implicitly.