# Javascript - change SQL datetime format

Tags: javascript, sql, datetime, format

I'm still new to programming, and am having trouble converting this date.  I'm using ajax with a chat application, and pull the date from SQL Server database record but can't seem to convert it.  The line of code getting the date is simply:

```
var timeStart = results.d[i].CreateDate;
```

the result I get is:  /Date(1365692153250)/

I tried adding 'new Date( )' before, and/or '.format(MMMM ...)' after.  This is probably an easy one, but I've looked all over. Please let me know if any additional info is needed. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you can better coerce the server to produce a decent format? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075683/sql-server-create-date

Comment: That's a .Net serialized date, here's how:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016847/converting-net-datetime-to-json

Comment: @mattmanser - that link helped.  If I could mark your comment the answer, I would.  Thank you

Comment: @deebs No problem, annoyingly SO converted the answer to a comment and I couldn't see how to undo it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @mattmanser for this thread, which answered my question... [Converting .NET DateTime to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016847/converting-net-datetime-to-json)

Solution:

```
var timeStart = results.d[i].CreateDate.replace(/\/Date\((-?\d+)\)\//, '$1');
var d = new Date(parseInt(timeStart));
```

I hate to 'answer my own question' but want to provide the solution to anyone else who may need it.

Answer (score 1):

I think this question and answers will help you:
[Convert a Unix timestamp to time in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847185/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-time-in-javascript)

You just need to convert your timestamp.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to construct a `Date()` and use the getters to build up the format.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

For passing in a format, you will want to include your own library, here is one solution for generating it:
http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format